# Использование автоматического List секционирования совместно с Range субпартициями

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Пытаюсь создать таблицу, разделив её на два уровня секционирования.

1. Первый уровень, это лист ключей, которые обновляются время от времени, и нежелательно участие DBA для создания партиций, если новый ключ будет добавлен. Поэтому, тут желательно автоматическое секционирование.
2. Второй уровень, записи по дням по колонке с типом `date`.

Пробую так:

```
CREATE TABLE PartitionedTable ( 
    id number, PartitionKey number, created date
) 
PARTITION BY LIST (PartitionKey) AUTOMATIC
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (created) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
( PARTITION p_PartitionKey VALUES (1) ( 
    SUBPARTITION p_created VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2000','dd-MON-yyyy')))
);
```

, но получаю:

> ORA-14179: An unsupported partitioning method was specified in this context.

Версия: *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production*

Есть ли какая-либо возможность, создать такую двух-уровневую структуру с минимальными затратами на администрирование при вставке записей с новыми значениями ключей секционироания?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56163025

Answer (score 2):

[Проблема кроется тут](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__BABGCEFI):

> Interval partitioning is not supported at the subpartition level.

Автоматическое секционироание не поддерживается на уровне субпартиций, ни для интервалов, ни для листов.

Поэтому, нельзя решить задачу с *interval-automatic partitioning* на уровне субпартиций. Какой бы способ секционирования не взять, всё равно потребуется пересекционирование субпартиций.

Если главная цель, сократить временные затраты по администрированию (суб)партиций,
то возможно самое удачное решение - *interval-list* секционированная таблица с субпартицией по-умолчанию для ключей листа.

В любое время можно изменить шаблон для субпартиций. Он определяет, какие субпартиции будут созданы сразу по-умолчанию при создании новой партиции.

Например, так будет создана *interval-list* таблица:

```
create table partitionedtable ( 
  id              number,
  partitionkey    number,
  created         date
) 
partition by range (created) interval (numtodsinterval(1,'day'))
subpartition by list (partitionkey) 
subpartition template  (
  subpartition p1 values ( 1 ),
  subpartition pdef values ( default )
) ( 
  partition p2000 values less than ( date'2019-01-01' )
);

insert into partitionedtable values ( 1, 1, date'2019-01-02' );
insert into partitionedtable values ( 1, 2, date'2019-01-02' );
```

Записи со значением нового ключа 2 окажутся в субпартиции по-умолчанию.
Если это случится, надо изменить шаблон субпартиций и предусмотреть в нём значение нового ключа:

```
alter table partitionedtable
  set subpartition template (
    subpartition p1 values ( 1 ),
    subpartition p2 values ( 2 ),
    subpartition pdef values ( default )  
  );

insert into partitionedtable values ( 1, 1, date'2019-01-03' );
insert into partitionedtable values ( 1, 2, date'2019-01-03' );

select partition_name, subpartition_name, high_value 
from   user_tab_subpartitions;

PARTITION_NAME    SUBPARTITION_NAME    HIGH_VALUE   
P2000             P2000_P1             1             
P2000             P2000_PDEF           default       
SYS_P772          SYS_SUBP771          default       
SYS_P772          SYS_SUBP770          1             
SYS_P776          SYS_SUBP773          1             
SYS_P776          SYS_SUBP774          2             
SYS_P776          SYS_SUBP775          default
```

Теперь, новая партиция (`SYS_P776`) уже имеет субпартицию для ключа 2. Ранее созданная партиции (`SYS_P772`) осталась без изменений, и потребуется пересекционирование, если необходимо перенести записи с ключём 2 в новую субпартицию.

Предположим, `created` => дата вставки, это значит, что надо только пересекционировать субпартиции, созданные между временем первой вставки с таким значением ключа и временем изменения шаблона субпартиций. То есть, в отличии от автоматического секционироания, для каждого нового ключа, надо будет позаботиться о
субпартициях в недавно созданных партициях.

При таком изменении схемы секционирования, возможны также другие сложности. Перед  тем как "засучить рукава", проверте, подходит ли это решение для других требований для секционирования, таких как, производительность, архивация данных и т.д..

<sub>ответ от @ChrisSaxon</sub>

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Спасибо за правки! Кроме обычных опечаток, ещё и некторые клавиши заедают ((

Answer (score 2):

Ни один из способов автоматического секционирования, ни *interval*, ни *list*, не поддерживается на уровне субпартиций.

Возможно лучше, пересмотреть структуру секционирования и отказаться от субпартиций вообще. Введённое в версии 12.2 [*автоматическое list секционироание*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/partition-create-tables-indexes.html#GUID-12150FFB-48E4-4169-9EBE-64974C1CEF2A) допускает использование [*составных ключей*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/partition-create-tables-indexes.html#GUID-6A4131B1-BBDF-4230-B88C-80BC91A0C861) или [*виртуальных колонок*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/partition-create-tables-indexes.html#GUID-AF6D08D7-5E0F-4E08-B682-74CCCAEC64D1). При этом, административные затраты, например, необходимость заботится о новых ключах, будут сведены к минимуму.

Можно попробовать так:

```
create table parttab (
    id number, 
    key number, 
    created date, 
    partkey varchar (16) as (
        to_char (key, 'FM099999')||'-'||to_char (created, 'yyyymmdd')) virtual 
)
partition by list (partkey) automatic (partition pdefault values ('000000-19000101'))
;

insert into parttab (id, key, created) 
    select rownum id, trunc (rownum/5)+1 key, date'2019-01-01' + trunc (rownum/4)
    from xmlTable ('1 to 6')
; 

6 rows inserted.
```

Где-то так будут выглядеть только что созданные партиции:

```
select partition_name, high_value, num_rows
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name = upper ('parttab') 
;

PARTITION_NAME   HIGH_VALUE           NUM_ROWS
---------------- ------------------ ----------
PDEFAULT         '000000-19000101'           0
SYS_P1588        '000001-20190101'           3
SYS_P1589        '000001-20190102'           1
SYS_P1590        '000002-20190102'           2
```